# railsをherokuにデプロイした際のエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

RailsアプリをHerokuでデプロイしようとしてるんですが、

```
git push heroku master
```

を実行した時にエラーが出てしまいます

remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:        sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     ht(t)ps://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to evening-reaches-48365.
remote:
To ht(t)ps://git.heroku.com/evening-reaches-48365.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/evening-reaches-48365.git'

原因がしりたいです
信用度が足りずにリンクを複数投稿できなかったため、一部httpの部分をht(t)pと記述を変更しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> emote: ! Failed to install gems via Bundler. remote: ! Detected
>   sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku: remote: !
>   ht(t)ps://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

に書いてあるように、Herokuではsqlite3がサポートされていないためエラーとなっているようですね。

Herokuにデプロイする環境向けに、PostgreSQLなどをDBとして利用するように設定してあげると良いと思います。以下のRailsTutorialを参考にしてみてください。

[railtutorial]https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/beginning?version=5.0#sec-heroku_setup